# LWJGL Cannot create a cube with VBO

Tags: java, arraylist, lwjgl, vbo

While trying to create a cube using a VBO in java, I found that only one face of the cube is rendered (and incorrectly as well). The code is below, can somebody tell me why it wont render more than a single side?

## Render class

```
package engine;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBindBuffer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBufferData;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glGenBuffers;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Render{

    private int amountOfVerts;
    private int vertexSize = 3;
    private int colorSize = 3;
    private FloatBuffer vertData, colorData;
    private int handle, colorHandle;
    private ArrayList<Cube> cubes = new ArrayList<Cube>();

    public Render() {
        addCube(new Cube(new Vector3f(0,0,0)));
        amountOfVerts = cubes.size() * 72;
        vertData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVerts * vertexSize);
        createCubeArray();

        colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVerts * colorSize);
        colorData.put(new float[]{1f,1f,1f, 1f,1f,1f, 1f,1f,1f, 1f,1f,1f});
        colorData.flip();

        handle = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle); //sets the current buffer to this
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // fills the new buffer / stores data
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbinds

        colorHandle = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle); //sets the current buffer to this
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // fills the new buffer / stores data
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbinds
    }

    public void createCubeArray(){
        for (int i = 0; i < cubes.size(); i++){
            Cube c = cubes.get(i);
            storeVertexData(c.getData());
        }
    }

    public void storeVertexData(float[] data){
        vertData.put(data);
        vertData.flip();
    }

    public void addCube(Cube c){
        this.cubes.add(c);
    }

    public void removeCube(Cube c){
        this.cubes.remove(c);
    }

    public void render(){
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle);
        GL11.glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle);
        GL11.glColorPointer(colorSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, amountOfVerts);
        GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    }


}
```

## Cube class

```
package engine;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Cube {

    private Vector3f pos = null;
    private float cubeSize = 100f;

    public Cube(Vector3f pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public float[] getData(){
        return new float[] {    pos.x,pos.y,pos.z,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y,pos.z,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z,
                    pos.x,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z,

                    pos.x,pos.y,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z + cubeSize,

                    pos.x,pos.y,pos.z,
                    pos.x,pos.y,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z,

                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y,pos.z,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z,

                    pos.x,pos.y,pos.z,
                    pos.x,pos.y,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y,pos.z,

                    pos.x,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z,
                    pos.x,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z + cubeSize,
                    pos.x + cubeSize,pos.y + cubeSize,pos.z,
                };
    }

}
```

## Edit

```
public Render() {
    addCube(new Cube(new Vector3f(0,0,0)));
    amountOfVerts = cubes.size() * 24;
    vertData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVerts * vertexSize);
    createCubeArray();
    vertData.flip();
    colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVerts * colorSize);
    float[] color = new float[amountOfVerts * colorSize];
    Arrays.fill(color, 1f);
    colorData.put(color);
    handle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle); //sets the current buffer to this
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // fills the new buffer / stores data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbinds

    colorHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle); //sets the current buffer to this
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // fills the new buffer / stores data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbinds
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are currently rendering you need to have as many floats in your color buffer as you have in your position buffer (if you have less it just uses 0 for the rest of the values for me, though I'm not sure if this will happen for you).

```
float[] color = new float[amountOfVerts * colorSize];
Arrays.fill(color, 1f);
colorData.put(color);
```

Also you are flipping your position buffer after each `float[]` you add to it, which means you will overwrite your previous data. You should only flip it once you are done adding to it.

Your `amountOfVerts` should be `cubes.size() * 24` instead of `cubes.size() * 72` as well.

Comment: Now nothing at all is rendered. I added the new code (Check the section "Edit"). Yeah the cubes.size() * 24 makes sense now, isn't it the number of vertices of the shape * the number of faces of the shape? @Alex

Comment: And the way you are rendering your cube it is 4 vertices per face * 6 faces.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figured that out!